# Windows 10 with ssd cache or ssd custom install?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, hard-drive-cache

I have a Samsung Ultrabook series 5 Ultra. It has 500GB HDD with Windows 8 and a 22GB with two partitions, used by Condusiv Express Cache to improve disk access speed. The HDD died, could not recover anything from inside - it does a noise of an old vinyl disk scratched...

So I bough an new and faster HDD and a Windows 10. Samsung does not provide (I didn't find) much software for Windows 10 yet, there is no Express Cache install and Condusiv Tech does not talk with simple people. I try one Asus package and it works, but it says it was not licensed for the system and does nothing. There is one provided by Lenovo but will have the same issue, though.

Windows 10 runs "ok", even with no cache and only 2GB of RAM, it is better than Windows 8, though. But there is no point leaving the 22GB of SSD unused. I did a Mac OS X work with only 10GB once, so I'm wondering if I can do it with Windows 10 by formatting the 22GB in one single bootable partition. Maybe put the users in HDD and the Windows, virtual memory etc., and Program Files in 22GB - will be enough? Is this better than keep trying to install an Express Cache? There is another solution for my ultrabook?

Comment: What about [ReadyBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost)?

Comment: Sounds very interesting! Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As there is low interest for this question, and I need to make choices, I'll post here what I have decided to do.

1) I found the documentation of the notebook, so I'll try online help, see if they will provide an installation for my Windows 10.

2) If they don't, or don't work at all, I'll try [Intel Rapid Storage Technology](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/pt-br/download/25165/Driver-RAID-do-Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-?product=55005)

3) May won't work, because as log chipset is modern Intel, the board is Samsung made, so I'll try a cheap third part caching software as [veloSSD](https://www.elitebytes.com/VeloSSDTrial.aspx) from Elite Bytes, should do the job.

4) Nothing work, ok, so I'll just define swap file (virtual memory) to the SSD. It's not the best use for it, but is better than nothing, right?

By the way, for those wish to spend some money, there is some solutions that use RAM memory as L1 cache (got to upgrade RAM) and a flash drive as L2 cache. But is kinda server solution, maybe to much for a laptop, I won't.